# Find 2nd max salary using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have following sql query for finding 2nd max salary.

```
Select * From Employee E1 Where
    (2) = (Select Count(Distinct(E2.Salary)) From Employee E2 Where
        E2.Salary > E1.Salary)
```

I want to convert it into Linq statement.

Comment: You want to find the employee who has the second-highest salary?

Comment: @Ian: Yes,I want to find second highest salary using Linq

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think what you're asking is to find the employee with the second-highest salary?

If so, that would be something like

```
var employee = Employees
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Salary)
    .Skip(1)
    .First();
```

If multiple employees may have equal salary and you wish to return an IEnumerable of all the employees with the second-highest salary you could do:

```
var employees = Employees
    .GroupBy(e => e.Salary)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .Skip(1)
    .First();
```

(kudos to @diceguyd30 for suggesting this latter enhancement)

Comment: I would say that the generated SQL is the prerogative of the underlying LINQ provider and shouldn't generally be of concern. It should be possible to write LINQ queries without considering what SQL will be generated (or indeed whether SQL will be generated at all)..

Comment: @Santosh, @Lan Nelson, This is not an answer to question if there are i.e 5 salary which are max, it's not a solution, see my answer.

Comment: @Saeed:Let me try your solution.

Comment: @santosh to make this work you need only add `.GroupBy(e => e.Salary)` above the 'OrderBy' line and change the 'OrderBy' to order the result by 'Key' instead of 'Salary'  Then the query will return a list of all the employees that make the second highest salary.

Comment: @diceguyd30:I am not getting you can you give an example?

Comment: Updated my answer to include @diceguyd30's observation about multiple employees with equal salaries.

Comment: The "more than one" stuff above doesn't work for me. This is because the "GroupBy(e=>e.Salary)" turns all the multiple same salaries into one so I can't get all the employees with the second highest salary (I only get one). It does works if there are multiple empoyees with highest salary, then it will only bring back the 1st employee with the second highest. Does this make sense?

Comment: This will work for duplicate records also  

emplist.OrderByDescending(x => x.Salary).Select(x=>x.Salary).Distinct().Take(3).Skip(2).First();

Answer (score 5):

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
{
    new Employee { Id = 1, UserName = "Anil" , Salary = 5000},
    new Employee { Id = 2, UserName = "Sunil" , Salary = 6000},
    new Employee { Id = 3, UserName = "Lokesh" , Salary = 5500},
    new Employee { Id = 4, UserName = "Vinay" , Salary = 7000}
};

var emp = employees.OrderByDescending(x => x.Salary).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You should include some explanation, not just code.

Answer (score 2):

You can define equally comparer class as bellow:

```
    public class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee >
    {
        #region IEqualityComparer<Employee> Members
        bool IEqualityComparer<Employee>.Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            // Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
                return true;

            // Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;

            return x.Salary == y.Salary;
        }

        int IEqualityComparer<Employee>.GetHashCode(Employee obj)
        {
            return obj.Salary.GetHashCode();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

and use it as bellow:

```
    var outval = lst.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id)
                  .Distinct(new EqualityComparer()).Skip(1).First();
```

or do it without equally comparer (in two line):

```
        var lst2 = lst.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).Skip(1);
        var result = lst2.SkipWhile(p => p.Salary == lst2.First().Salary).First();
```

**Edit:** As Ani said to work with sql should do : `var lst = myDataContext.Employees.AsEnumerable();` but if is for commercial software it's better to use TSQL or find another linq way.

Comment: +1 A nice idea, but won't work with LINQ to SQL. You'll have to pull everything back to the client and use LINQ to Objects. I'm unsure if the OP can afford to do this.

Comment: @Saeed:I am getting this error "The query operator 'SkipWhile' is not supported.".I am using C# 4.0

Comment: @santosh, use first one, equality comparer.

Comment: @Ani, you saying `var outval = lst.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).Distinct(new EqualityComparer()).Skip(1).First();` not works? if is so yes you are right (I didn't test it) but else I think It's better to SQL instead of linq, or @santosh, if database size is not big you can do `ToList` and then use it, thanks Ani.

Comment: @Saeed: LINQ to SQL won't be able to turn the `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation into T-SQL.

Comment: @Saeed:I am trying your first query and getting this error message **Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Distinct'.**

Comment: @santosh: To get this to work, try `var lst = myDataContext.Employees.AsEnumerable();` (or similar) before this code. You should be aware of the consequences of doing this; all the filtering will run on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Using **LINQ**, you can find the 3rd highest salary like this:

```
// first use LINQ to sort by salary, then skip first 2 and get next
var thirdHighestSalary= (from n in db.Employee order by n.salary descending select n).distinct().skip(2).  FirstOrDefault()
// write the result to console
Console.WriteLine(Third Highest Salary is : {0},thirdHighestSalary.Salary);
```

Comment: Hi @MIltanMiltan!  Any chance you could edit your answer to be formatted with code blocks, and to explain why your code solves the problem so that the person asking knows how to fix this in the future (rather than just handing over the code without an explanation of why it works)?  Thanks, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

This will work for duplicate record as well as nth highest salary just need to play with take and skip thats all for ex below is for 3 rd highest salary with duplicate record present in table-

```
emplist.OrderByDescending(x => x.Salary).Select(x=>x.Salary).Distinct().Take(3).Skip(2).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IList<int> intList = new List<int>() { 10, 21, 91, 30, 91, 45, 51, 87, 87 };

        var largest = intList.Max();

        Console.WriteLine("Largest Element: {0}", largest);

        var secondLargest = intList.Max(i => {
            if(i != largest)
                return i;
            return 0;
        });

        Console.WriteLine("second highest element in list: {0}", secondLargest);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably delete this answer, the top voted answer is a better solution.